Can I use the sollution to the heat equation for a 1D diffustion problem like I have?
So, I have some source of heat at point $x=0$, from which i don't know the temperature as function of time $T(0,t)$, I do however have $T(x_{NTC},t)$ and i want to know the temperature at some point x. I have thought up some solution, but I dont know If it is valid.
let us start with the general solution to a the 1D heat equation given some heatsource
$$
T(x_{NTC},t) = \int_0^t \frac{1}{\sqrt{4D\pi (t-t')} }\frac{dT(0,t')}{dt'}\exp{\left[ -\frac{x_{NTC}^2}{4D(t-t')} \right]}dt'\\
 =\int_0^t \frac{dT(0,t')}{dt'}D(x_{NTC},t-t')dt'.
$$
We can fourier and reverse fourier transform $D(x_{NTC},t-t')$ giving
$$
T(x_{NTC},t) =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} D(x_{NTC},\omega)\int_0^t \frac{dT(0,t')}{dt'}e^{-i2\pi \omega t'}dt'e^{i2\pi \omega t} d\omega,
$$
( https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConvolutionTheorem.html ) meaining
$$
T(x_{NTC},\omega) = D(x_{NTC},\omega)\int_0^t \frac{dT(0,t')}{dt'}e^{-i2\pi \omega t'}dt'.
$$
This holds for any point $x_{NTC}$, meaning we can make a second equation that holds for x, substituting the integral we find
$$
T(x,\omega)=\frac{T(x_{NTC},\omega)}{D(x_{NTC},\omega)}D(x,\omega)
$$
which is easily solved numerically. However I dont know whether all steps taken are sufficiently justified or even allowed.
I hope you could validate my thinking/math, maybe give me some search terms to find papers that explore this such that I can use this in my research. If you have some physical intuition that would help me explain why this would work that would be lovely, now i just trust the math.
Kind regards!

What are the boundary conditions?
